# Template Strings in GoLang?

Tags: string, templates, go

i've been researching for a while now but could not find anything.

For Example

```
var name = "tom"
sentence := "My Name is #{name}"
```

In JS this works with ${var} and in ruby with #{var}

So are there Template Strings in GoLang ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The Solution is

```
sentence := fmt.Sprintf("My Name is %s", name)
```

Answer (score 14):

The better way is using template. It allows you to specify a name.

```golang
sentence := "My Name is {{ .name }}"
templ := template.Must(template.New("myname").Parse(sentence))
templ.Execute(os.Stdout, map[string]interface{}{
    "name": "tom",
})
```

Comment: That's a lot of code for such a simple task. Isn't there any way to make it shorter?

Comment: I agree with @matronator, however, compare to the sprintf solution below, this is answering the need for something like a templating engine for Go asked in the question.

Comment: This is an unavoidable drawback of using Golang. We can only reduce the amount of code by wrapping this code into a function that passes in a string and a map.